# PowerBI - Visual API - changing Visual properties | usage: translations

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-api, powerbi-rest-api

Context : we're having our powerbi dashboards embedded either as a whole report or only standalone visuals.

We want to translate the content of our reports in several languages. some of it can  be done via  metadata translations ( DAx Editor -> cultures).

What we want to achieve is to have the visuals titles etc translated. we are looking for a way which is easy to maintain.

According to MS this could be achieved using the Visuals API but the documentation is new and we cannot interpret if we can use it for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/visual-api

Would there be someone who did this before and give some directions?

Answer (score 0):

Visual API is used to create custom visuals for Power BI. Currently, Power BI translates report content such as automatically generated titles, filters, and tooltips using locale settings. but it doesn't translate your data.

You can update your embed configuration like this:

```
let embedConfig = {
    ...
    settings: {
        localeSettings: {
            language: "en",
            formatLocale: "es"
        }
    }
};
```

> (Note: After the report has been loaded, the locale settings cannot be
> changed. To change the report locale settings, reset the iframe by
> calling powerbi.reset(element), and then embed the report again)

The alternative approach could be to create multiple reports/visuals for each language and embed them separately.

For Instance, if I need to a visual in English and Spanish language. I'll make two visuals, one in Spanish and another in English, as well as a dropdown/input field. I'll update the configuration file and re-render the component based on the user's selection/input.

**References:**

[Configure embedded Power BI report settings in a Power BI embedded analytics application | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#locale-settings)

[Supported languages and countries/regions for Power BI - Power BI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/fundamentals/supported-languages-countries-regions)

Comment: When you say " but it doesn't translate your data automatically." what do you mean by that?

Comment: Typo, I meant to say "but it doesn't translate your data"